# Выбрать из БД предыдущий и следующий id

Tags: mysql

```
sub show_ourwork {
my $hash = {};

if ($id) {
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ourworks WHERE hidden=0 AND id=?");
    my $rvs = $sth->execute($id) or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
    $hash = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
          $hash->{data} = join(".", reverse(split(/-/, $hash->{data})));
    if ($hash) {
        my @images = ();
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE pid=? and ptype=? ORDER BY id");
        $rvs = $sth->execute($id, 'ourwork') or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
        while (my $images = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
            push(@images, $images);
        }
        if (@images) {
            $images[-1]->{last} = 1;
            $hash->{images} = \@images;
        }
        $hash->{name} =~ s/"/\&quot;/gm;
        $hash->{owner} =~ s/"/\&quot;/gm;



    } else {
        $hash->{text} = "Запрашиваемая работа не обнаружена";
    }




    $sth->finish;
} else {
    $hash->{text} = "Запрашиваемая работа не обнаружена";
}


&tmpl_print("tmpl/client.show_ourwork.tmpl", {%$hash, %$conf});
```

}

CGI выполняет. Id передается в `$QUERY_STRING`, и этот скрипт выбирает из БД нужную мне позицию. Как мне сюда добавить код, чтобы на выходе получить 2 массива с следующим и предыдущими заполненными ID? Т.е. чтобы поставить ссылки "следующая\предыдущая" позиция вида $nextid и $previd.

Пробовал добавить

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM database WHERE id < $id  LIMIT 1");
```

Но скрипт не отрабатывает. Теряет `id`. Два раза `if ($id)` делать?

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите получить на выходе три массива? Сама эта запись + пред + след?

Comment: Да, именно так 3 массива.. Весь скрипт обновил в шапке. Как мне в него добавить то, что я описал.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что `UNION` Вам поможет.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("(SELECT * FROM database WHERE hidden=0 AND id<" . $id. " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM database WHERE hidden=0 AND id>" . $id. " ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)");
my $rvs = $sth->execute() or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
```

Comment: Не подходит. Мне нужно получить 2 разных массива, кроме основного. А в Вашем примере будет 1 массив. Я обновил код в шапке.